# angle made by vector with the plane

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

Let the angle between the vector a and vector b is $\pi/6$, between vector b and vector c is $\pi / 4$ and between vector a and vector c is $\pi /3$. Then what is the angle made by vector with the plane which is containing vector b and vector c.

My try :

[image]

Comment: To avoid having too many variables why don't you take the vector $a$ to be the $i$ vector, and $b$ to be $(\sqrt3,1)$? Then you'll have only two unknowns for the unit vector $c$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Yes , I already did that which is approach for objective question and I am looking for a subjective approach